# How to remove extra commas in csv with Perl

Tags: perl

I've done this before with sed, but I would like to know how this is done in Perl.
I have an CSV file that looks something like this:

```
IFB, Northpole, Alaska, 907-555-5555,,,,
Walmart, Fairbanks, Alaska,,,,,
Chicken, Anchorage, Alaska, 907-555-5555,,,,,
Beef, Somewhere,,,,, Over the Rainbow,,,907-555-5555
etc...
```

What I need is to remove the extra commas, but not the single commas separating the values.  This means I need to remove any occurrence of more than 1 commas, no matter where it occurs in the file.
Desired output:

```
IFB, Northpole, Alaska, 907-555-5555
Walmart, Fairbanks, Alaska
Chicken, Anchorage, Alaska, 907-555-5555
Beef, Somewhere, Over the Rainbow, 907-555-5555
```

Comment: I see no colons here at all. Do you mean commas?

Comment: This can be done with [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). You need to show some research effort, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Example output based on your input would go far. Any fields that might have embedded commas? I have no idea what `I need to remove any occurrence of more than 1 column, no matter where it occurs in the file` means.

Comment: What if row 1 is `foo,,bar,baz` and row 2 is `pony,unicorn,zebra,giraffe`? If you remove the empty field, row 1 will only have 3 columns, while row 2 will have 4 columns; processing this data consistently would now be very difficult.

Comment: Do you mean something like `perl -pe 's/,*$//' filename`, to remove all trailing commas from each line? I'm not certain from your description.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write comma, not colon.

Comment: @Wintermute: Your example would work but it only remove commas at end of line, where I still need  duplicates gone in between values. I've updated my example.

Comment: I never wrote column not sure how it got changed to column from colon but either way I meant to write comma.

Comment: desired output adds a space before "Over"; I'm guessing that was an error?

Comment: assuming so, and that you want *all* trailing commas gone, not just all but one, `s/,+(?=[,\n])//g`.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

while(<DATA>) {
    s/,+[\t ]*/, /g; # Remove extra commas
    s/ $//g;         # Remove trailing space
    print;
}

__DATA__
IFB, Northpole, Alaska, 907-555-5555,,,,
Walmart, Fairbanks, Alaska,,,,,
Chicken, Anchorage, Alaska, 907-555-5555,,,,,
Beef, Somewhere,,,,,Over the Rainbow,,,907-555-5555
etc...
```

You can also use Perl as `sed` with `perl -pe`:

```
cat myfile | perl -pe 's/,+[\t ]*/, /g;'
```